# Rollbar integration with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano3, rollbar

I am currently using capistrano as a deployment tool and want to integrate rollbar so I can track my deployments.

There installation instructions are simple

Capistrano 3
Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rollbar', '~>2.11.3'
```

Add to your Capfile:

```
require 'rollbar/capistrano3'
```

Add to your deploy.rb:

```
set :rollbar_token, 'MY_TOKEN'
set :rollbar_env, Proc.new { fetch :stage }
set :rollbar_role, Proc.new { :app }
```

I have followed the steps, no errors during deployment and all works fine, however its not appearing in the 'deploys' area on rollbar.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`set :rollbar_role, Proc.new { :app }`

In my case, the `:app` role was not in use. After changing it to a role my project uses, I was able to see Rollbar's logs in the capistrano log. The notifications went out successfully.